# Many-sorted nominal sets as sheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

The category of nominal sets can also be presented as the Schanuel topos, the category of sheaves on $\mathbb{I}^\mathsf{op}$ under the atomic topology, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the category of finite sets and injective maps.

A covariant presheaf on this category exhibits a well-behaved renaming action, but the sheaf condition for the atomic topology ensures that there is a well-behaved notion of *support* (i.e. if a "term" seems to only use some subset of the available symbols, it has a unique seed at the world that *only* contains those symbols, which is the same as the original modulo renaming/weakening).

Now, I am hoping that it is possible to generalize this to the many-sorted case, where we replace $\mathbb{I}$ with $\mathbb{I}\downarrow \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a discrete category of sorts. $\mathbb{I}\downarrow \mathcal{S}$ is essentially a category of "atom contexts", with pairs $(U, s)$ of symbols sets $U$ and sort-assignments $s:U\to \mathcal{S}$ as objects and sort-preserving renamings as morphisms, i.e. $\varrho : (U,s) \to (U',s')$ for $\varrho:U\to U'$ such that for all $u\in U$, $s(u) \equiv s'(\varrho(u))$.

So, my thought is that to get a many-sorted version of this apparatus, I could simply take $\mathbf{Sh}((\mathbb{I}\downarrow \mathcal{S})^\mathsf{op})$.

Does this yield the "right" construction? Not being terribly familiar with sheaves, at first I am worried that I may have incurred some unintended obligations, but I figured I would check here in case anyone has any insight, or has done something along these lines.

**UPDATE**: I've been thinking a bit about the relationship between this an Pitts's multi-sorted nominal sets (where he takes a global sort assignment $s:\mathbb{A}\to\mathcal{S}$, and cooks up a category of $s$-sorted nominal sets $\mathbf{Nom}_s$). It seems like for any such $s$, from one of my sheaves one should be able to cook up a nominal set in $\mathbf{Nom}_s$; likewise, if you have a got a family of nominal sets $(\mathbf{Nom}_s)_{(s\in\mathcal{S})}$, from this it seems like one ought to be able to construct one of these sheaves.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{I} \downarrow \mathcal{S}$ supposed to say that there are many different sets of atoms, or do you want it to serve a different purpose? For instance, how do you intend to use $(U, s)$ where $s$ is a constant function? My instinct woudl be to have instead a family of atom sets $\mathbb{I}_s$ one for each sort $s$.

Comment: Hi Andrej, sorry for the confusion. In your example, if $s$  is a constant function, then $(U,s)$ is modeling a context of atoms that all have the same sort. (I hope this clears things up, but if it hasn't, I'm happy to go into more detail.)

This is analogous to the use of the comma construction $\mathbb{F}\downarrow\mathcal{S}$ to model variable contexts in Fiore, Hamana and others' work on second-order universal algebra, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the category of finite sets and any maps.